# Xcode weird naming convention for ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I'm creating a new file, a subclass of a UIViewController via the Xcode wizard that pops up through new > file.

I'm naming the file "747ViewController" and it spits out the .h/.m files fine.

However inside the files, the interface and implementation names are odd:

They show up as `@interface _47ViewController : UIViewController` and `@implementation _47ViewController`

Are you not allowed to start with a number or something? Should I leave it or rename it to what I want it? Thanks

Comment: You should pick a different class name. Usually classes start with an abbreviation of whatever set of code they belong to (NS for Next Step, CF for core foundation, AB for Address Book, etc). If your project's abbreviation is actually 747, I would use SFSFooBar for all it's class definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct: just like in C and C++ your identifiers can not start with a number. The workaround from Xcode is correct: Unlike Java, the source file name and the class name do not have to be the same.